# Cassandra: sstabledump output

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

After flushing data from the memtable, SS Table files are created in the Cassandra data folder like mc1-big-Data.db, mc-1-big-Index.db, mc-1-big-Filter.db etc.

When the sstabledump command is used with any of the above files, the same output is getting displayed on the console. I tried by giving mc1-big-Data.db, mc1-big-Summary.db and mc1-big-Statistics.db, but the dump was same for all files.  Does the same output get dumped for every SSTable file in the columnfamily?

I have provided the command that I ran and the output below:

```
sstabledump /var/lib/cassandra/data/db/ind- 
92435570d5ea11e88863fb30b1341a80/mc-5-big-Index.db
WARN  15:00:58,110 Small commitlog volume detected at 
/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; setting commitlog_total_space_in_mb to 7158.  
You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  15:00:58,179 Small cdc volume detected at /var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw; 
setting cdc_total_space_in_mb to 3579.  You can override this in 
cassandra.yaml
WARN  15:00:59,874 Only 13.161GiB free across all data volumes. Consider 
adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
[
{
 "partition" : {
  "key" : [ "5" ],
  "position" : 0
},
"rows" : [
  {
    "type" : "row",
    "position" : 38,
    "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2018-10-22T12:01:04.857982Z" },
    "cells" : [
      { "name" : "player_name", "value" : "Rohit" },
      { "name" : "runs", "value" : 65 }
    ]
  }
]
},
{
 "partition" : {
  "key" : [ "1" ],
  "position" : 39
 },
 "rows" : [
  {
    "type" : "row",
    "position" : 74,
    "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2018-10-22T11:10:11.419697Z" },
    "cells" : [
      { "name" : "player_name", "value" : "Sachin" },
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the files named `mc-1-*`together make up 1 sstable. The data is in the `mc-1-big-Data.db` file and the others are more or less what the name suggests: an Index, Filter, etc. The next sstable will have files named `mc-2-*` and so on.

Use sstabledump on the `*Data.db` file to see what data is in your table.

[Here's a reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html)

edit:
Checking the source code and asking on the cassandra IRC channel, I was able to find out that you can use any file in the sstable to dump the data. Also many thanks to [Alex Ott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18627/alex-ott) for his help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @LHWizard . I am aware that all the mc-1-* files together constitute one sstable. I had referred the link that you have given previously and according to that, I thought the data would be in mc-1-big-Data.db file and I did get the data there. But when I experimented with the index, compression, statistics files, I got the same output that I got in the Data file. The output that I have put in my question is from the index file and it was exactly same as that of the data file.

Comment: I'll get some clarity on that. I'll edit my answer when I do.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. What if I want to dump only the contents of the index? How do I do that if all the files dump the data.